# How to load in jupyter a table from txt file from a certain sentence using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab

I am trying to load a table from a txt file, but I want to start loading from a certain word 
in this case this is the file and I want to start from the numbers beneath the sentence >>>>Begin....

[image]

I know about the `skiprows` command but not all tables start at the same line

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is not super efficient way to do this but i try to filter necessary data and append to df using below script:

```
import re
import os
import pandas as pd

def foo(file_name):
    # create empty df
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ab'))
    pat = r'>+[a-zA-Z ]*<+'
    pat2 = r'[-0-9.]*'    
    start_save_to_df = False
    # set path
    with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'src',file_name)) as f:
        for row in f.readlines():            
            if start_save_to_df:
                val1, val2 = [float(val) for val in re.findall(pat2, row) if val]
                # append data
                df = df.append({'a': val1, 'b': val2}, ignore_index=True)
            if re.search(pat, row):
                start_save_to_df = True
    return df
```

I hope it's helps you.

Comment: At the end I just changed it myself, but maybe next time I'll try your solution